# Cant traverse up correctly with jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, parent, dom-traversal

I want to simply traverse upwards to find the parent element and wrap an a around it.

**This is what I have so far:**

```
$(".product_thumbnail a").each(function() {
    var hrefsrc = $(this).attr('href');
    console.log(hrefsrc);

    $(this).parent('.animate').wrap('<a href="'+hrefsrc+'"></a>');
});
```

And this is the HTML structure:

```
<ul id="someIDs">
<li class="animate">
    <div class="product_thumbnail_wrapper ">
        <div class="product_thumbnail ">
            <a href="url">
                <span class="product_thumbnail_background" style=""></span>
                <img width="300" height="300" src="url" />
            </a>
        </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

Cant figure out how to correctly trigger the right element.
I tried the following methods:

> closest()
>
> parent()
>
> parents()

parentsUntil shows that the wrapping is possible.
I also read the jQUery traversing doc but that didnt help much.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: So you are trying to wrap a hyperlink... in a hyperlink? That's a really bad idea.

Comment: i kill it afterwards. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `li.animate` element is not the direct parent of your `a` element you can't use `parent` and you need to use the `parents` function, however - not that it will give you all the parents up the DOM tree.

If you don't have more than 1 it should be ok, but if you do it will not work as you want.

Here is the fix to your code, but you should really change it so the final output would be a valid HTML structure.

```js
$(".product_thumbnail a").each(function() {
    var hrefsrc = $(this).attr('href');
    $(this).parents('.animate').wrap('<a href="'+hrefsrc+'"></a>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="someIDs">
  <li class="animate">
      <div class="product_thumbnail_wrapper ">
          <div class="product_thumbnail ">
              <a href="url">
                  <span class="product_thumbnail_background" style=""></span>
                  <img width="300" height="300" src="url" />
              </a>
          </div>
      </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

> Also important - note that `<a>` is an inline-block element and should not wrap  blocking elements (such as `<div>`). Another issue is that `<ul>` elements should only have `<li`> child-elements (And not `<a>` - like what you are doing).

What you can do instead is change the `<a>` element into `onclick` function on the `li`:

```js
$(".product_thumbnail a").each(function() {
    var hrefsrc = $(this).attr('href');
    $(this).parents('.animate').click(function() {
      window.location = hrefsrc;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="someIDs">
  <li class="animate">
      <div class="product_thumbnail_wrapper ">
          <div class="product_thumbnail ">
              <a href="url">
                  <span class="product_thumbnail_background" style=""></span>
                  <img width="300" height="300" src="url" />
              </a>
          </div>
      </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

It will work the same and the structure now is valid.

Comment: As per HTML5, you can use `<a>` to wrap block-level elements ;) the restriction is no longer there. However, your point about `<li>` must be a descendent of `<ul>` is still very valid. What you want is to use [`.wrapInner()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapinner/) instead.

Comment: HTML5 gives us a lot of new great things, but when we talk about reality - IE11, edge, safari and other browsers still have problems there and the final outcome will not work exactly as we really think it would :)

Comment: I'm quite sure IE9 uses standards mode when encountering `<!DOCTYPE html>` (which is the HTML5 doctype), so that point is kinda moot actually.

Comment: @BillBronson it will not work because your `li` elements don't have the `animate` class. It is probably something that another script is adding. Open the source of the page (right click, view-source) and search for `animate` in that page. There is no single `<li>` element with that class.

Comment: I told you specifically to right click =>view source :) https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwKk0.png

Comment: Ok strange. But how can i select the parent li then?

Comment: Did you try `parents('li')` ?

Comment: almost! it was ".product_thumbnail_wrapper". Thank you a lot mate for helping me to understand whats wrong with my code and to understand traversing! <3